# phpmyadmin Designer Tab meaning of different colors?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Ok, so I clicked on the Designer tab in phpmyadmin to see the relationships between my tables.  There are a lot of different colors connecting the foreign keys from one table to the other table.  The colors are blue, green, yellow, purple and red.  It is obvious that green means that the relationship is a valid one and I think the same thing is true of blue.  I guess yellow means caution (or warning) and I suppose that red means that this relationship is a bad one and should be deleted.

My questions are:  1) Why the different colors? 2) What does each color mean? 3) If red means that the relationship is wrong, why is it wrong and how do I fix it?

I am including my SQL tables structure in case you want to look at it and tell me what is wrong with the way I have structured my tables or why the foreign key relationship is wrong and how it needs to be fixed.

This is a PHP/MySQL quiz application that keeps track of member results.  I might be organizing these tables all wrong.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot guys, you guys are awesome and have helped me a lot.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.10.1deb1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Feb 15, 2014 at 12:56 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.35
-- PHP Version: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `Asheville_Potpourri`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `answers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
  `id_answer` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `answer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `addedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_answer`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `bannedUsers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bannedUsers` (
  `id_bannedUser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bannedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reasonBanned` text NOT NULL,
  `dateBanned` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_bannedUser`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `bannedBy` (`bannedBy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `blogPosts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogPosts` (
  `id_blogPost` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_blogTopic` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `blogPostTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `blogPostContent` text NOT NULL,
  `postedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datePosted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_blogPost`),
  UNIQUE KEY `blogPostTitle` (`blogPostTitle`),
  KEY `id_blogTopic` (`id_blogTopic`),
  KEY `postedBy` (`postedBy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `blogTopics`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogTopics` (
  `id_blogTopic` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blogTopicName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `blogTopicDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `addedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_blogTopic`),
  UNIQUE KEY `blogTopicName` (`blogTopicName`),
  KEY `addedBy` (`addedBy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `feedback`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feedback` (
  `id_feedback` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text NOT NULL,
  `dateSent` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_feedback`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `forumPosts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forumPosts` (
  `id_forumPost` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_forumTopic` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `forumPostTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `forumPostContent` text NOT NULL,
  `postedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datePosted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_forumPost`),
  UNIQUE KEY `forumPostTitle` (`forumPostTitle`),
  KEY `id_forumTopic` (`id_forumTopic`),
  KEY `postedBy` (`postedBy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `forumTopics`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forumTopics` (
  `id_forumTopic` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `forumTopicName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `forumTopicDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `addedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_forumTopic`),
  UNIQUE KEY `forumTopicName` (`forumTopicName`),
  KEY `addedBy` (`addedBy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints` (
  `id_memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dateUpdated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints` (`memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `memberProfilePages`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `memberProfilePages` (
  `id_memberProfilePage` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `profileImageFilename` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `facebookAddress` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `twitterAddress` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dateUpdated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_memberProfilePage`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints` (`memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `memberQuizNameAnswers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `memberQuizNameAnswers` (
  `id_memberQuizNameAnswer` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_quiz` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quizNameQuestionNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_answer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isCorrect` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dateQuizTaken` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_memberQuizNameAnswer`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `id_quiz` (`id_quiz`),
  KEY `quizNameQuestionNumber` (`quizNameQuestionNumber`),
  KEY `id_answer` (`id_answer`),
  KEY `isCorrect` (`isCorrect`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `memberQuizNameResults`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `memberQuizNameResults` (
  `id_memberQuizNameResult` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_quiz` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quizNamePointsEarned` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_memberQuizNameResult`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `id_quiz` (`id_quiz`),
  KEY `quizNamePointsEarned` (`quizNamePointsEarned`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `questions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `id_question` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `addedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_question`),
  KEY `addedBy` (`addedBy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `quizCategories`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quizCategories` (
  `id_quizCategory` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoryName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `categoryDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `addedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_quizCategory`),
  KEY `addedBy` (`addedBy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `quizNameAnswers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quizNameAnswers` (
  `id_quizNameAnswer` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_quiz` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quizNameQuestionNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_answer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isCorrect` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_quizNameAnswer`),
  KEY `id_quiz` (`id_quiz`),
  KEY `quizNameQuestionNumber` (`quizNameQuestionNumber`),
  KEY `id_answer` (`id_answer`),
  KEY `isCorrect` (`isCorrect`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `quizNameQuestions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quizNameQuestions` (
  `id_quizNameQuestion` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_quiz` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_question` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quizNameQuestionNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_quizNameQuestion`),
  KEY `id_question` (`id_question`),
  KEY `quizNameQuestionNumber` (`quizNameQuestionNumber`),
  KEY `id_quiz` (`id_quiz`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `quizzes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quizzes` (
  `id_quiz` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_quizCategory` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quizName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `quizDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `addedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_quiz`),
  KEY `id_quizCategory` (`id_quizCategory`),
  KEY `addedBy` (`addedBy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `emailCode` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `active` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `passwordRecover` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userType` enum('1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `dateRegistered` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userName` (`userName`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `answers`
--
ALTER TABLE `answers`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `answers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`addedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`);

--
-- Constraints for table `bannedUsers`
--
ALTER TABLE `bannedUsers`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `bannedUsers_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `bannedUsers_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`bannedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `blogPosts`
--
ALTER TABLE `blogPosts`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `blogPosts_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_blogTopic`) REFERENCES `blogTopics` (`id_blogTopic`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `blogPosts_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`postedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `blogTopics`
--
ALTER TABLE `blogTopics`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `blogTopics_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`addedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `forumPosts`
--
ALTER TABLE `forumPosts`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `forumPosts_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_forumTopic`) REFERENCES `forumTopics` (`id_forumTopic`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `forumPosts_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`postedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `forumTopics`
--
ALTER TABLE `forumTopics`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `forumTopics_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`addedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints`
--
ALTER TABLE `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `memberProfilePages`
--
ALTER TABLE `memberProfilePages`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `memberProfilePages_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `memberProfilePages_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints`) REFERENCES `memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints` (`id_memberAllQuizzesTotalPoints`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `memberQuizNameAnswers`
--
ALTER TABLE `memberQuizNameAnswers`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `memberQuizNameAnswers_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `memberQuizNameAnswers_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`id_quiz`) REFERENCES `quizzes` (`id_quiz`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `memberQuizNameAnswers_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`quizNameQuestionNumber`) REFERENCES `quizNameQuestions` (`quizNameQuestionNumber`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `memberQuizNameAnswers_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`id_answer`) REFERENCES `answers` (`id_answer`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `memberQuizNameResults`
--
ALTER TABLE `memberQuizNameResults`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `memberQuizNameResults_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `memberQuizNameResults_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_quiz`) REFERENCES `quizzes` (`id_quiz`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `questions`
--
ALTER TABLE `questions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `questions_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`addedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `quizCategories`
--
ALTER TABLE `quizCategories`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `quizCategories_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`addedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `quizNameAnswers`
--
ALTER TABLE `quizNameAnswers`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `quizNameAnswers_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`quizNameQuestionNumber`) REFERENCES `quizNameQuestions` (`quizNameQuestionNumber`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `quizNameAnswers_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_quiz`) REFERENCES `quizzes` (`id_quiz`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `quizNameAnswers_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`id_answer`) REFERENCES `answers` (`id_answer`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `quizNameQuestions`
--
ALTER TABLE `quizNameQuestions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `quizNameQuestions_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_question`) REFERENCES `questions` (`id_question`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `quizNameQuestions_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_quiz`) REFERENCES `quizzes` (`id_quiz`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `quizzes`
--
ALTER TABLE `quizzes`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `quizzes_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_quizCategory`) REFERENCES `quizCategories` (`id_quizCategory`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `quizzes_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`addedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 5):

the only reason for different colors is to make it easier to distinguish them.

Comment: Sim, how does that not provide an answer? The questions asked were "1) Why the different colors? 2) What does each color mean? 3) If red means that the relationship is wrong, why is it wrong and how do I fix it?" and given the answer to the first question, the second and third are irrelevant. I don't understand your comment at all.

Comment: I think the point of Sim's comment was that Marc's comment doesn't help in any way.  I understand that the different colors make it easier to distinguish them.  But the question is, what does the color mean as it pertains to the table relationships?  For instance, does green mean "that relationship is fine and dandy", yellow means "that relationship works but its not advised", and red means "that relationship is wrong and not allowed."  Not that I am right, I am asking if any knows what the colors signify.

Comment: The only thing I have found that is even close to an answer is this:  "The green and blue relation link colors don't mean anything; they just help distinguish the individual joins in the spaghetti that can result from many links crowding into the same space. Red, however, indicates links reserved for deletion"  Okkkkkk, what does that mean?  And there are other colors besides just green, blue and red.  There are also yellow and purple lines.  So what do THOSE mean?  And what does "Red, however, indicates links reserved for deletion."?

Comment: Jason, you assumed that the colors meant something in terms of the relationships, and I replied that the *only reason* for different colors is to distinguish them. Therefore, the colors don't mean anything in terms of relationships.

Comment: But I think you are wrong Marc.  If I change the relationship, the color changes as well.  Each relationship doesn't have its own unique color.  I could be wrong but I think that the colors signify something.

Comment: Jason, I am a phpMyAdmin developer; so is Isaac Bennetch. Here is a quick test I just did: I have a designer schema with three tables and two relation lines. I open a different browser and for the same schema, the colors for relationships are different than those seen in the first browser.